# How to get all text from different elements under one div

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have problem, here is html pseudocode:

```
<div class="content" id="ui6" role ="tabpanel">
 <p> text </p>
 <ul> <li> text2 </li>
      <li> text3 </li>
 </ul>
  </div>
```

I want to get text, text2 and text3 and print them, but I can only manage to get "text".

Here is the code:

```
List<WebElement> sectionThreeText = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#ui6"));
    for(WebElement e : sectionThreeText) {
        System.out.println(e.getText());
    }
```

I tried also find it by:

```
css = "#ui6 > p ul"
xpath = "//*[@id=ui6]"
xpath = "//*[@id=ui6]/*"
xpath = "//*[@id=ui6]/p | //*[@id=ui6]/ul"
```

I am out of ideas. Where I make mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print **text**, **text2** and **text3** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.content#ui6")).getText());
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content' and @id='ui6']")).getText());
  ```

---

As an alternative you can also use the following *Locator Strategies*:

- To print **text**:

  - *cssSelector*:

    ```
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.content#ui6>p")).getText());
    ```
  - *xpath*:

    ```
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content' and @id='ui6']/p")).getText());
    ```
- To print **text2**:

  - *cssSelector*:

    ```
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.content#ui6 ul>li")).getText());
    ```
  - *xpath*:

    ```
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content' and @id='ui6']//ul/li")).getText());
    ```
- To print **text3**:

  - *cssSelector*:

    ```
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.content#ui6 ul li:nth-child(2)")).getText());
    ```
  - *xpath*:

    ```
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content' and @id='ui6']//ul//following-sibling::li[2]")).getText());
    ```

Comment: this should do the job. my approach was to iterate through the elements for additional fun.

Comment: I tried to get all in one line of code, but gave up. This did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Jsoup you can retrive the HTML page

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
    Elements divs = doc.select("div");
    for(Element elem : divs){
      System.out.println(elem.html()); //get all elements inside div
    }
```

Comment: this would print texts from all the divs in the page

Answer (score 0):

To get `text2` and `text3` use xpath `//*[@id="ui6"]/ul/li` not `xpath = "//*[@id=ui6]/p | //*[@id=ui6]/ul"` as you have mentioned. `//*[@id="ui6"]/ul/li` This xpath will help get all `li` elements inside `ul`

Answer (score 0):

You can get all descendants of the `ui6` element with `xpath(".//*")`.

Try this:

```
WebElement sectionThreeText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ui6"));
List<WebElement> childs = sectionThreeText.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
for(WebElement e: childs )
{
    System.out.print(e.getText());
}
```